# Multipart base64 image posting in java

Tags: java, string, image, base64, httpurlconnection

I have a httpurlconnection code that is meant to post data to server. When I am trying to send small data it's ok but whene i try to send a base64 image string the string is not received properly at server. I have checked the base64 converted string from jpg and the encoding is ok. So, there is something wrong with the http process that's making the string corrupted. Initially I thought that probably it's the big images that's causing the problem but on using a very small image only transfers part of the image to server and the rest is corrupted.
Can somebody suggest me how can I send a base64 image string to server. My code is as below:

```
HttpURLConnection hpcon= (HttpURLConnection) Url.openConnection();
        hpcon.setRequestMethod("POST");
        hpcon.setConnectTimeout(5 * 1000);
        hpcon.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter osw= new OutputStreamWriter(hpcon.getOutputStream());
        osw.write(data);
        osw.close();
```

The data is something like:

> key=YeP1r&nodeId=5&typeId=9&status=0&eventImage=imageString

Comment: @Anirudh it's other parameters like key used and base64 image string and other such parameters required by server for processing.

Comment: you are not setting any content-type, have you tried setting `Content-Type` explicitly?

Comment: should it be "text/plain" or I need to add something specific for base64?  hpcon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

Comment: check this quesion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210332/post-data-java-with-httpurlconnection

Comment: @NandkumarTekale already did that. I don't know why but everytime I add a line to my code that tries to specify any content type-either utf or multipart-no image is posted to the server. Infact no request is sent to the server. if I remove those lines the image is sent but as mentioned before it is corrupted.

Comment: should be worth looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104499/response-write-base64-string

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find a straight solution using HttpUrlConnection.
Used: httpClient from apache. 
Actually pretty easy to use.
[Last example multipart](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html)